# Permutations of tuples in range

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

When I call `permutations(range(0,nCols))` it will give me a permutation like this:

`(0, 1, 2)
(0, 2, 1)
(1, 0, 2)
(1, 2, 0)
(2, 0, 1)
(2, 1, 0)`

But what I want in addition to the above permutation is the tuples containing less than `nCols` items, so things like:

`(0)
(1)
(2)
(0, 1)
(0, 2)
(1, 2)`

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    # permutations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BA BC BD CA CB CD DA DB DC
    # permutations(range(3)) --> 012 021 102 120 201 210
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(n)
    cycles = range(n, n-r, -1)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
    while n:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            cycles[i] -= 1
            if cycles[i] == 0:
                indices[i:] = indices[i+1:] + indices[i:i+1]
                cycles[i] = n - i
            else:
                j = cycles[i]
                indices[i], indices[-j] = indices[-j], indices[i]
                yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices[:r])
                break
        else:
            return
```

Comment: I don't understand what is your actual problem.

Comment: It is a idiotic way ... Have a function --- `def perms(iterable): for i in iterable: permutations(i)`

Answer (score 3):

Since you posted the code from the module itertools.permutations below, you should pretty much see it right away. The "r" argument in

```
def permutations(iterable, r=None):
```

is the length the permutations should have. You can just loop over the range from 1 to n (length of the iterable) like this:

```
from itertools import permutations
for i in range(1,nCols+1):
    print(list(permutations(range(nCols),i))
```

This assumes that you really meant permutations. In your example, the 2-length permutations were not complete.

Comment: This is good buts its giving me it's not giving me what I need. It's giving me `[(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2, 1),
(1, 0, 2), (1, 2, 0), (2, 0, 1), (2, 1, 0)]`. The (0,) extra comma is messing up my program I think.

Comment: @nodebase,you cannot have a single item tuple without a comma

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to be a copy of itertools.permutations, so I will use that here:

```
from itertools import permutations

all_permutations = []

for index in range(1, nCols+1):
   all_permutations += permutations(range(nCols), index)

print(all_permutations)
```

Note that the second parameter `r` specifies the length of the permutations to generate. So, we can loop through and generate all the permutations for each length up to nCols. And boom!